# Desktop icons not clickable

Tags: icons

Just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04. First thing I encountered was that desktop icons don't work, eg. nothing happens when double-click. A menu appears when right click, but after selecting "Open" nothing happens. If I start "Files" app first and close it, all Icons start working normally for short period of time. Then they become inactive again. And work again only if I wake them up by Files app. Any of that wasn't happening on 16.04 before.